# Mapping column dataframe with list Python

Tags: python, list, pandas

How to create new column and set values which are results of mapping this dataframe with another object for instance list of lists python?

I have pandas dataframe:

```
{'a': [15,10,11,9,7,8], 'b':['smth','smth','smth','smth', 'smth', 'smth'].
```

And list of list:

```
[[15,10], [11], [9,7,8]]
```

I want create new column in my dataframe, which will be contain 3 big classes like in my list of lists.

I mean, I want to get this:

```
{'a': [15,10,11,9,7,8], 'b':['smth','smth','smth','smth', 'smth', 'smth',
'new_column': [0,0,1,2,2,2]}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far; also I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, seems like you can just use `dataframe['new_column'] = ...` from what you've shown so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where` in a list comprehension:

```
In [926]: import itertools

In [927]: l = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*[[15,10], [11], [9,7,8]], fillvalue=0))).T

In [928]: df['new'] = [np.where(l == i)[0][0] for i in df.a.values]

In [929]: df
Out[929]: 
    a     b  new
0  15  smth    0
1  10  smth    0
2  11  smth    1
3   9  smth    2
4   7  smth    2
5   8  smth    2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` created by `dict comprehension`, values of list has to be unique:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [15,10,11,9,7,8], 'b':['smth','smth','smth','smth', 'smth', 'smth']})

L = [[15,10], [11], [9,7,8]]
#https://stackoverflow.com/q/45349225/2901002
d = { v : i for i,vs in enumerate(L) for v in vs}
#alternative solution
#d = {v: i for i in range(len(L)) for v in L[i]}
print (d)
{7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 0, 11: 1, 15: 0}

df['new_column'] = df['a'].map(d)
print (df)
    a     b  new_column
0  15  smth           0
1  10  smth           0
2  11  smth           1
3   9  smth           2
4   7  smth           2
5   8  smth           2
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps me =))

Comment: Unfortunately only one solution can be accepted, another solution was better?

Comment: You have my vote because I think your solution is clean. +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you. I think your solution is overcomplicated. And also list comprehension is the best avoid in `pandas` with some exceptions.

Comment: I think what happened is that OP wanted to accept both solutions, but didn't know only one can be accepted. They probably accepted yours first no?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Myne was accepted first, but only 5 seconds ;)

Comment: Don't worry. You will get back your well deserved +15 soon, once OP understands what's the problem :)

Comment: Thank you :) Haha I am a pythonista. However, I do know the basics of other languages (c, java, full stack, apex, etc). My top answer is essentially how to split a number into two parts. It's so basic that I am embarrassed it is at the top. I have written hundreds of better answers. xD Started pandas recently as I am going into a data sciences masters course next month. It will help,