# Nested list to dict with count groups

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have nested list:

```
L = [[15,10], [11], [9,7,8]]
```

and need count groups like `[15, 10]` is `0` group, `[11]` is `1` group and `[9,7,8]` is `2` group - output is dictionary:

```
print (d)
{7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 0, 11: 1, 15: 0}
```

I try:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(L)}
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 0, 11: 1, 15: 0}
```

I think my solution is a bit over-complicated. Is there some better, more pythonic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using:

```
d = {v: i for i,l in enumerate(L) for v in l}
```

which generates:

```
>>> {v: i for i,l in enumerate(L) for v in l}
{7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 0, 11: 1, 15: 0}
```

The idea is as follows: first we iterate over `L` with `enumerate(L)` and we thus obtain the *index* `i` of the sublist `vs`. Next we iterate over every element `v` in `vs`. For every `v` we associate `v` with `i` in the dictionary.

If there are collisions - a value that occurs twice in `L` - then the last index will be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
d = {v: i for i in range(len(L)) for v in L[i]}
```

output:

```
{7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 0, 11: 1, 15: 0}
```

iterating over `L` using `range(len(L))` to access each list and assign each `value` as the `key` of the dictionary, and the index of the list as the `value`.